# When is LIMIT applied? Will it select all results before limiting?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm concerned about the performance of a query such as `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 5` on a very large user table. Will it select all records then limit to 5?

More specifically will the following query select all assetids before limiting...

```
SELECT * FROM assets WHERE asset_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) LIMIT 5
```

I realize it doesn't make sense to include all ids in the `IN()` clause if I'm limiting but I'd like to know how mysql behaves in this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your query. See this page for more explanations of how LIMIT is applied:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html

For that specific query, the following would apply:
"As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query unless you are using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS."

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will have to scan all rows by `asset_id` column, so you better have an index on it. In my experience, you would always want to set an `order by` clause also, since the result set will be internally (i.e. order unknown), and you would not know why the returned 5 results were the ones you actually wanted.

Comment: "Your query will have to scan" -- are you sure?